# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable colab research

Tags: python

I am using Python in colab research. I have this code to count cards and say how many full decks exist on 'A':

```
A = ["1P", "1C", "1O", "2P", "2C", "2O", "2E", "3P", "3C", "3O", "3E", "4P", "4C", "4O", "4E", "5P", "5C", "5O", "5E",
 "6P", "6C", "6O", "6E", "7P", "7C", "7O", "7E", "8P", "8C", "8O", "8E", "9P", "9C", "9O", "9E", "DP", "DC", "DO",
 "DE", "10P", "10C", "10O", "10E", "VP", "VC", "VO", "VE", "RP", "RC", "RO", "RE", "1P", "1C", "1O", "1E", "2P", "2C",
 "2O", "2E", "3P", "3C", "3O", "3E", "4P", "4C", "4O", "4E", "5P", "5C", "5O", "5E", "6P", "6C", "6O", "6E", "7P",
 "7C", "7O", "7E", "8P", "8C", "8O", "8E", "9P", "9C", "9O", "9E", "DP", "DC", "DO", "DE", "10P", "10C", "10O", "10E",
 "VP", "VC", "VO", "VE", "RP", "RC", "RO", "RE", "1P", "1C", "1O", "1E", "2P", "2C", "2O", "2E", "3P", "3C", "3O",
 "3E", "4P", "4C", "4O", "4E", "5P", "5C", "5O", "5E", "6P", "6C", "6O", "6E", "7P", "7C", "7O", "7E", "8P", "8C",
 "8O", "8E", "9P", "9C", "9O", "9E", "DP", "DC", "DO", "DE", "10P", "10C", "10O", "10E", "VP", "VC", "VO", "VE", "RP",
 "RC", "RO", "RE"]
B = {'1P': 0, '1E': 0, '1C': 0, '1O': 0, '2P': 0, '2E': 0, '2C': 0, '2O': 0, '3P': 0, '3E': 0, '3C': 0, '3O': 0,
 '4P': 0, '4E': 0, '4C': 0, '4O': 0, '5P': 0, '5E': 0, '5C': 0, '5O': 0, '6P': 0, '6E': 0, '6C': 0, '6O': 0,
 '7P': 0, '7E': 0, '7C': 0, '7O': 0, '8P': 0, '8E': 0, '8C': 0, '8O': 0, '9P': 0, '9E': 0, '9C': 0, '9O': 0,
 '10P': 0, '10E': 0, '10C': 0, '10O': 0, 'DP': 0, 'DE': 0, 'DC': 0, 'DO': 0, 'VP': 0, 'VE': 0, 'VC': 0, 'VO': 0,
 'RP': 0, 'RE': 0, 'RC': 0, 'RO': 0}

for i in range(0, len(A)):
  B[A[i]] += 1

min = min(B.values())
print(min)
```

I run the code once and it works, but if I run `min = min(B.values())` again, I get an error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: What do you mean by running it twice?

Comment: This code does not throw that error and outputs `2` to me, assuming proper indentations. This line `min = min(B.values())` should be outside loop.

Comment: I run the code and it works normal and say how many decks, but when i do it again i got that error

Comment: i work in colab research of google

Comment: I already fixed it, thank you

Comment: edited to clarify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the value to a variable other than `min`.

When you run `min = min(B.values())` you are re-assigning the function `min` to a number, so next time you run the code, `min` is no longer a function and you can't call it again.

Using a different variable name would solve the problem:

```
minvalue = min(B.values())
```

Comment: minvalue = min(B.values())

Comment: Glad that it fixed your problem Daniel